# How do I install my new ceiling light fixture?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling, light

[image: old light fixture]

Hi I’d like to install a new light fixture. The fixture is made out of plastic and has a blue and a brown cable.

The image is of the old fixture that works.

In case the image isn’t clear enough - The wires coming out of the ceiling consist of two black wires on the left hand side, then two red wires which are held together and two copper wires on the right hand side which are also held together

How would I install the new fixture?

Comment: I tried plugging the blue and brown cables into the sockets that the old fixture had, but this didn’t work.

Comment: What are we looking at here?  Is this the old fixture that works, and the wiring arrangement that works?  Or is this your first attempt with the new fixture?

Comment: Yes this is the old fixture- I’ll make that more clear in the question

Comment: Hi @WillMurray, did you ever get this resolved? If so, give a check mark to Owain's answer if that helped, or write up your own and give yourself a check mark so others know this has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Left to right is: neutral, switched live, looped live, earth.

New fitting should connect as the old one, blue to neutral, brown to switched live. The bare copper earths should have been sleeved green/yellow since 1977.

This looks like UK wiring, before any USA visitors get confused.